# Frame offset when using Moveit! on PR2

Tags: moveit, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note: cross-posted to moveit-users. Thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/SCAsmEuu9Tk)

I'm using ROS groovy on a PR2, and trying to use Moveit! for a pick & place application. I'm using the default `move_group.launch` file from `pr2_moveit_config`, along with the default `robot start` bringup.

When I look at rviz, the robot representations from the RobotModel and the PlanningScene do not line up, as seen below:

[image: image description]

Unfortunately, the PlanningScene frame is the one that's wrong when compared to the actual sensor data, as determined by observing where it thought the arm was positioned relative to displayed kinect points vs. where it actually is.

After noticing that this offset changed a little every time I restarted the move_group node, I discovered that Moveit! uses `odom_combined` and the transform to `odom_combined` is published by the `robot_pose_ekf` node, and it wasn't 0 despite the robot being stationary. So, I tried killing that node, and using the static transform publisher to publish a 0 transform.

This seemed to help, but didn't fix the entire offset.

Is there some configuration step that I'm missing? Do I need to tell Moveit! to use a different frame? (If so, how, and which frame?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96246/frame-offset-when-using-moveit!-on-pr2/) by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1780 on 2013-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This goes away once I change the Fixed Frame in rviz. It doesn't seem to matter what to, so long as it gets changed.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1